# How can I cancel a notification when the user clicks on it?

Tags: android, notifications

I would like to create a notification that clears automatically when the user presses it and has no other behaviuour. The notification below works fine but when i press on it it takes me to the activity "MyActivity" (even having to define an intent seems a bit unecessary when I don't want to use it...)

Using FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

***Update:*** Sorry, I have found the FLAG_AUTO CANCEL does work, that is the notification is cleared from the status bar.  I guess I am really tring to write an intent that does nothing (or completely delete the intent).

***Code...***

```
             Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.success, res.getString(R.string.messages_sent), System.currentTimeMillis());

            //Define the expanded message and intent
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence contentTitle = res.getString("My content title");


            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0 );
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, mStrSuccessMessage, contentIntent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            //Pass the notification to the notification manager
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an empty intent without an actual action.

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You can have `MyActivity` exit immediately though: call `finish()` from `onCreate()`.