# How to write a notification that does absolutly nothing when clicked?

Tags: android, notifications

Ive seen many examples of how to make something happen when the user clicks on a notification but I actually don't want anything to happen.  If the user clicks on the notification I want the notification to simply dissapear and the user NOT taken anywhere.

In my code below, while FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL clears the notification  from the status bar, when the user clicks on a my notification they are taken to "MyActivity".

How can I create a notification that does nothing?

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.success, res.getString(R.string.messages_sent), System.currentTimeMillis());

        //Define the expanded message and intent
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = res.getString(R.string.messages_sent_ellipsis);


        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0 );
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, mStrSuccessMessage, contentIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        //Pass the notification to the notification manager
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I cancel a notification when the user clicks on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682009/how-can-i-cancel-a-notification-when-the-user-clicks-on-it)

Answer (score 28):

Changing

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
```

would do the job. The gist is if you want nothing, give it a blank intent.